# Arc length equal to distance travelled by a particle in a cycloid

Tags: calculus

How can I prove that the arc length is equal to the distance travelled by a particle in a cycloid.

I know the definition of arc length and that I can get it by multiplying the angle (radians) and the radius.

And with that I can get $x = r(t-\sin(t))$ and $y = r(1-\cos(t))$.

But I want to know, using math, why the distance travelled in the $x$-axis is equal to the length of the arc.

Thanks.

[Cycloid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J8DWj.jpg)

Comment: This is horribly written. I believe you are asking about what it means for an object to roll without slipping. You form a cycloid by following a dot on the edge of a circle as the circle rolls along the $x$-axis without slipping.

Comment: Yes it is horribly written, this is not my first language, I have posted a link "Cycloid" with an image explaining what I am saying, why the radius times theta is equal to the magnitude of vector OQ

Comment: Yes, it's precisely what I said. The arclength of the arc of the circle equals the distance the circle rolls along the ground. This is a physical notion, not a mathematical one. How do you say that the wheel/circle never slips?

Comment: "This is a physical notion, not a mathematical one." Im just learning about it in Vector calculus, if you think this is the wrong site for this question please let me know. What I want to know is how can I prove that "The arclength of the arc of the circle equals the distance the circle rolls along the ground", I know this is a fact, but is there a way that I can demonstrate this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure where you got that the distance traveled in the $x$-direction is equal to the arc length of a cycloid.

The distance traveled in the $x$-dimension is just the circumference of the generating circle, or $2\pi r$. We can confirm this using the parametrization in the question. We're given $x(t) = r(t-\sin(t))$, so through one rotation, we go from $t = 0$ to $t = 2\pi$, and we have:

$$ x(2\pi) - x(0) = 2r(2\pi-\sin(2\pi))-2r(0-\sin(0)) = 2\pi r .$$

To get to the arc length $S$ of one arch, we can integrate the differential $dS = \sqrt{{\left(\frac{dx}{dt}\right)^2 + \left(\frac{dy}{dt}\right)^2}} $ from $t = 0$ to $t = 2\pi$:

$$ S = \int_0^{2\pi} \sqrt{{\left(\frac{dx}{dt}\right)^2 + \left(\frac{dy}{dt}\right)^2}} \ dt $$
$$ = \int_0^{2\pi} {\sqrt{{\left(r-r\cos(t)\right)^2 + \left(r\sin(t)\right)^2}}} \ dt $$
$$ = \int_0^{2\pi} {\sqrt{r^2-2r^2\cos(t) + r^2\cos^2(t) + r^2\sin^2(t)}} \ dt $$
$$ = \int_0^{2\pi} {\sqrt{2r^2-2r^2\cos(t)}} \ dt $$
$$ = r\int_0^{2\pi} {\sqrt{2-2\cos(t)}} \ dt $$
$$ = 2r\int_0^{2\pi} {\sin\left(\frac{t}{2}\right)} \ dt $$
$$ = 4r \left[-\cos\left(\frac{t}{2}\right) \right]_0^{2\pi} $$
$$ = 8r . $$

Then, $2\pi r \neq 8r$, so the distance traveled in the $x$-dimension is not equal to the arc length.

Comment: I think I'm missing the word "particle", I mean "the distance travelled by a particle". x=r (t−sin(t)) comes from the asumption that the arc length (radius times theta) is equal to the distance travelled by the particle

Comment: "Radius times theta" would be $rt$, not $r(t-\sin(t))$. The equation $x = r(t-\sin(t))$ isn't giving you a distance, it's the parametrization of the $x$-coordinate of the cycloid in terms of the angle $t$. It's just saying that after the circle has gone through a rotation of $t$, the $x$-coordinate on the cycloid is at $r(t-\sin(t))$.

Comment: Maybe I am not making myself clear, this is not my first language, I have posted a link to an image explaining what I mean

Comment: My question is how can I prove that the radius times theta is equal to the magnitude of vector OQ

Comment: Ahhh, I see. I think this is what Ted Shifrin is getting at above with regards to the circle rotating without slipping. Imagine a piece of string wrapped around the circle, and as you roll the circle along the $x$-axis, the string unravels and is left behind. How much of the string has been unwrapped after a rotation through an angle of $t$? The proportion of the circumference of the circle that is represented by the angle $t$, i.e., $\frac{t}{2\pi}$. The total length is then that proportion times the circumference, which is $\frac{t}{2\pi}*2\pi r = rt$. Does that make it a bit clearer?

Comment: Thanks man it actually does make it clearer, although I was thinking maybe there is way to demonstrate the same thing by doing what you did earlier with the formula to get S, or maybe not, I am just starting with this subject, please forgive me.

Comment: No worries! Glad I could help. You can show that the arc length is that proportion of the circumference using calculus, but I don't think there's a way to demonstrate that's the same as the distance traveled through $x$, that's more of a physical assumption as Shifrin said.