# Why Doesn't the Arc Length Formula of the Cycloid have π in it?

Tags: calculus, circles, area, arc-length, cycloid

So basically what I was thinking is if a cycloid curve is made by a rolling circle then its length should include $\pi$ somehow. I understand it's not the same length as the circle itself ($2\pi r$), but how can $π$ disappear from the formula, namely $8r$?
While on the other hand the area under one arch of a cycloid is given by $3\pi r^2$, $3$ times the area of the rolling circle, so still includes the $\pi$.
Finally I have a small hypothesis ,that this happened because the actual distance covered by the circle includes $\pi$ (which is $2\pi r$) so maybe they cancel each other somehow but I have no clue how to show that.

Comment: btw I am not looking for a proof of the formula , just the intuition part

Comment: For a more general epicycloid also ( radius of base circle =a, of rolling circle =b) we have $ L/b =8 (1+b/a)$;  so check out your small hypothesis.

Comment: Maybe this: https://youtu.be/3yK2tJZR3Js

Comment: It's because the formula for the arc length involves integrating $\sin(\cdot)$, which gets you a $\cos(\cdot)$, and when you plug in your $2\pi$, you have $\cos(2\pi)=1)$. Here are the steps:  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4040056/arc-length-equal-to-distance-travelled-by-a-particle-in-a-cycloid/4040120#4040120

Comment: Andrew's video does a good job, though it completely ignores a difficulty (a sequence of curves can converge uniformly to another, but still have their lengths not converge to the limit curve's length - a famous example is approximating a unit circle with the boundary of a covering by small squares, whose length will always be $8$, no matter how small the squares). It can be shown that the problem doesn't arise for the method used, but that gets far deeper into the weeds than they wanted to go, so they just ignored the problem.

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang The video is good but its not exactly what I am looking for

Comment: @AmaanM ye thats the step that pi disappears in , so what i was thinking of if we integrate to some pi it cancels in the formula and vise versa , so in a circle we integrate from -r to r (rationals not pi) , and so pi shows in the formula , what i mean is that pi shows in either the limits of integration or the result formula not both

Comment: is it even possible to output some pi out of a cosine funtion from a rational input